# How to open a second form based on another completed form's ID?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, ms-access-2010

[Access 2010]

I am trying to link a form based on an initial form's unique ID (auto-generated string value). Here's a simple outline of database design:

Relevant Tables:

1. tblCruiseLog (CruiseLogID is primary key)
2. tblMasterStation (has MasterStationID field as primary key, with CruiseLogID field as foreign key)

Relevant Forms:

1. CruiseLog
2. MasterStation

Expected workflow:

1. Open CruiseLog, auto-generate CruiseLogID, fill out some fields (no issues).
2. Close CruiseLog form, go back to main switchboard, and open MasterStation form (no issues).
3. MasterStation form loads, creates a new record with an auto-generated MasterStationID, and auto-fills CruiseLogID with the CruiseLogID that was generated in Step 1 (???).

I am having trouble figuring out how to get the MasterStation form to carry over the CruiseLogID that was created in workflow step 1. Making the MasterStation a subform within the CruiseLog form is not possible, because the MasterStation form itself will have a subform within it. How can I accomplish this?

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use form/subform arrangement? Otherwise, code in CruiseLog sets a global variable or a TempVars variable that can be referenced by MasterStation.

Comment: I can't make it a subform because MasterStation itself has a subform within it. I want to fill out the CruiseLog, close it, and then continue to reference it with each successive MasterStation record. The CruiseLog info only gets filled out once at the beginning of the day, whereas MasterStation/subforms get filled out repeatedly at each new sampling station.

I'm not sure how to set a global variable

Comment: Do some research. I have given you topics to investigate. There are many examples. Maybe you can use form/subform/subsubform. Another approach to consider is demonstrated in http://www.fmsinc.com/MicrosoftAccess/Forms/Synchronize/LinkedSubforms.asp.